# Not able to get the nifi processor group status

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi. I have define a processor group in Nifi and I have started the dataflow.

From the backend, how can I check the status of the processor group whether it is running or not?.

I tried

```
/bin/nifi.sh status
```

But it only gives the overall nifi status whether it is running or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't see status of a process group because process groups do not have status
. Nifi just adds a added log like this

```
  2021-04-09 13:26:44,766 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroup StandardProcessGroup[identifier=feffff20-c806-305a-5d38-2b8def09bebe] added to StandardProcessGroup[identifier=1be26a7f-0175-1000-6d70-e5784c0dde33]
```

you can see the IDs in 'Operate' table on the right side of canvas.

[image]

On the other hand processor based logs can be seen

```
  2021-04-09 13:40:59,290 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled QuickFixInitiator[id=31ee54ea-5043- 3415-6f6e-4b8df429188f] to run with 3 threads

  2021-04-09 13:45:31,164 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Stopped scheduling QuickFixInitiator[id=31ee54ea-5043-3415-6f6e-4b8df429188f] to run
```

also via rest api

```
 http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/processors/31ee54ea-5043-3415-6f6e-4b8df429188f
```

It is hard to follow [nifi rest api doc](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) All the UI requests go through rest api so the best way to learn it watching UI requests in developer console -> network tab

[image]

Comment: Is there any curl command to check the status of processor group. Also When i make the rest api i get the message "unable to find the processor"

Comment: you can use curl command as well. it is a basic http request. I edited my answer to show rest requests. see requests in developer console while clicking in UI and use them in curl